# 9 Patch png not working correctly for background

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm trying to create a background image for my app that will look sharp on all resolutions/orientations.

I'm new to android development, but I understand the easiest way to achieve this is to use 9 patch images. I thought I understood how they worked, but I can't get it to work.

I've created a background image @ 768 x 1280 which is the resolution of my Nexus 4. When I don't 9 patch it and view it on my device, it looks fine (obviously, because the resolution/orientation matches the device's):

[image]

So it looks nice and sharp.

But then I add the patches onto the image using the `drawer9patch.bat` file and rename the file to '.9.png' and this is the result:

[image]

Knackered!

The strange thing is: in the preview pane in the right hand side of the draw9patch tool it all looks fine....

I've also tried making the image at a smaller resolution, but the logo & text don't look sharp; they look pixelated...

I feel there must be some vital piece of the puzzle I'm missing? The area I've defined as content is being stretched?

Here is my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/my_background_image_patched"
    android:padding="0px">
<!-- Login controls here --->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my 9 patch image (which is located to the 'drawable' folder):

[image]

Comment: I have posted the 9 patch.. it's the last image? I'll add the code..

Comment: Yes, sorry I just saw it so removed the comment. The Image seems okay. And tell where did you put it (res folder name).

Comment: On the other hand. I would suggest to add bottom padding area for whole image. And why is vertical padding only on stretch line? I would make it full height.

Comment: its in the 'drawable' folder..

Comment: it would be a better idea to put it in corresponding density folder or drawable-nodpi if it's used for app densities. I don't see any obvoius mistakes, so I am not sure. If I were you I would try to add paddings as I told in comment above. Maybe it's the way missing padding areas are treated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by either of those two suggestions...Can you explain what you mean by padding? Are you referring to the stretch markers or content?

Comment: stretch markers are top and left black pixels. The right / bottom black pixels mark padding area. I suggest to fill the 9 patch right and bottom sides with full black pixels (e.g. make the image full padded)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I tinkered with your 9 patch.
I must say it was poorly designed (72 dpi, while it should really be 320 dpi).

So, I redesigned it (you can see I moved the black pixels) and saved it to 320 dpi (in the drawable-xhdpi folder).

It seems it scaled well at ldpi and mdpi screens (so, I guess it will also scale well at hdpi):

[image]

The patch I used is this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's sorted it!

Comment: Annoyingly I was using Microsoft Expression Design to create the image, which has a limit of 300dpi! So I can't create a 320dpi image :\

Comment: Use mine... It's already at 320 dpi. For the future, you can use Paint.net (freeware) or Gimp (also freeware) (I'm too busy now to look on Google, but you'll do it in 5 secs)

Comment: Good idea. I can copy my vectors from expression into paint.net @ 320dpi =)

Comment: New tools in the toolbox! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Try to generate Nine-Patch using this [Nine-patch Generator](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch) allows you to quickly generate simple nine-patches at different screen densities, based on the specified source artwork